# How can I create a receive-only sdp offer of webrtc?

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I know how to create a send-only offer by add "OfferToReceiveVideo:false" and "OfferToReceiveAudio:false" in param MediaConstraints in this method:

```
public void createOffer(SdpObserver observer, MediaConstraints constraints)
```

But how can I create a receive-only sdp offer? I try to create it by adding no media stream to peer connection, however, it will cause sdp very short and no line "a:recvonly" contains. And no ice candidate generated.

I want to create a webrtc peer connection to receive media stream, but not send.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. 
Set "OfferToReceiveAudio" and "OfferToReceiveVideo" to "true" in MediaConstraints. And do not add stream.

Comment: I want to do reverse of your case. How Can I do that?